ssh proxy not asking for certificate passphrase on jump server
I am trying to do the following:

Keep a "master" private key on my Windows machine and move all my keys and connections info into a multipass ubuntu 24.04 instance (hosted locally via VM, called "external") on which it has it's own ssh "config" (planning to make an ubuntu instance portable in the future and I'm just testing the concept for now).

SSH from the Windows machine to another machine ("orange") that has it's authentication private key and connection info saved within "external" machine's "config". "orange" is accessible through a jump server ("banana") only and it's resolved there.

All machines ("orange", "yellow", "pink" etc) don't have any public IPs and have to go through one jump server or another ("banana", "carrot" etc).


My Windows "config":
Host external
    HostName 172.20.133.156
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile C:/users/Workstations/.ssh/masterKey.pem
    ForwardAgent yes

Host orange
    ProxyCommand ssh external ssh -vvv -F /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config orange

My "external" ssh "config":
Host banana
 HostName 123.123.123.123    # redacted public IP of the jump server
 User bananaJumpUser
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bananaJumpKey.pem
 ForwardAgent yes

Host orange
 HostName orange
 User orangeUser
 ProxyJump banana
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/orangeKey.pem

If I directly use in my Git Bash (Windows) the command:
ssh -t external ssh orange

it works just fine, but when I put things together in the Windows ssh "config" file, it  tries to connect through "banana" machine (jump server), but it doesn't prompt me for the passphrase that the private key has and  fails with error: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Log extracts (-vvv): https://pastebin.com/qmJEiw44 (can't post the entire log due to "This looks like spam" message)
It doesn't prompt me for the certificate passphrase.
The /dev/tty access:
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 Aug  8 17:45 /dev/tty which is  globally accessible. I thought that's the issue at first.
Another thing that I've found strange is:
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/bananaJumpKey.pem type -1

Normally the type should be >= 0. I've checked permissions with both 600 & 400, nothing changes. owner is "ubuntu" also.
I've also tried to add the -t flag on the ProxyCommand, even -tt has no effect.
Another thing that I find strange is:
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/bananaJumpKey.pem  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/bananaJumpKey.pem
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
bananaJumpUser@123.123.123.123: Permission denied (publickey).

By my understanding, at this point it should've prompted me to enter the passphrase, but it doesn't show anything and says "no passphrase given".
My ssh_config and sshd_config have the PasswordAuthentication yes and KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Is this even possible?
I don't want to strip my private keys's passphrases.
As it works correctly using ssh -t external ssh orange the problem should not be it...
Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it!
P.S: I might be using wrong terms here and there, sorry for that - still learning some things.

...what exactly are you trying to do, and why?

@Massimo Hi there, thanks for your reply. The goal is to move my keys and authentication configurations from my Windows ssh "config" to a local Ubuntu instance (which I’ll refer to as "external").
My objective is to establish connections to other servers afterwards from Windows machine by first connecting to the "external" Ubuntu instance using a "master" key that remains on the Windows machine. Once connected to the "external" instance, I want to use the keys and configurations stored there to connect to other servers. I would like not to store many keys on the Windows machine itself.
